# How to start a Thread within another thread and keep it alive?

Tags: java, multithreading

Inside first thread I need to create another thread.

```
Thread thread2 = new Thread(bworker);
thread2.start();
```

The problem is that when first thread finishes it's job, thread2 get's terminated though it has more work to do.

How can I keep it alive until it finishes it's work?

I don't want to use join because it will block the flow of the first thread.

Comment: But if the first thread has already finished its work and you add the join at the end what is the problem?

Comment: Join at the end of thread1.  Then there will be nothing to block.

Comment: before start your thread created by daemon thread, set it as non daemon thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second thread *won't* be automatically terminated when the first thread finishes. That's not how threads work. The only thing like that is that the whole *process* will terminate if there are no non-daemon threads alive. Assuming that's not the situation here, I think your diagnostics are messed up around the second thread - or it's dying for some other reason.

Comment: Since setDaemon is not set the former thread would be daemon just as well, I think the OP has some other error.

Comment: @bestsss: Indeed - that's my guess too.

Comment: If a thread dies (TERMINATED ) it  becomes a simple java object where GC rules will be applied to it.

Comment: @JavaMain: I don't see how your comment is relevant - could you clarify? I don't think the scenario is the one you're describing at all.

Comment: I wanted to point out that  when the thread dies  it does not mean it is the end of anything created inside that same thread.

Comment: @JavaMain: Again, I don't see how that's relevant to this question, to be honest. (And this question is nearly 8 years old...)

Answer (score 0):

`thread.isAlive()` is better option to know whether a thread is alive or not.

You can use while loop and `isAlive()` to block the thread getting terminated

Comment: There's no need to do that, and if you're *just* going to loop until another thread has finished, `join()` is a much cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the second thread outside the run() method of the first thread, and call start() inside the run() of first thread. This might solve your problem. If it does not, there's problem in your second thread code.

Example: http://pastebin.com/rx2eYQG2